Merging two time series into single in Grafana Dashboard
I want to plot a Timeseries of TPS of few APIs in Grafana Dashboard. But the challenge is I want to extract the URIs based on Joining 2 Queries as below.
Example :
Following query returns the identifier and URI combinations ( Value would be something else that can be ignored ) :
sum by (identifier,uri) ( custom_metric_total{identifier=~"${idenfiers}" ) 

Following query returns the URI and respective TPS :
(sum(rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{}[1m])) by (uri))

I want to prepare a timeseries of the IDENTIFIER-URI combination ( Only URIs which exist in both results ) using the values of TPS. Main objective is to MERGE Series1 and Series2 based on URI and retrieve the Value from Series1 and Identifier from Series2.
Can someone experienced with it set me in right direction on how to achieve this through some query changes or Transforms.

Simple Hack that worked for my case was to Just ADD The two Time Series through expression itself.
It just drops whichever don't have common labels ( in my case URI ) and returns the value of the Series1 + Series2. Since I don't need Series2 Value, I just replaced the Series2 Query to return 0 by multiplying it.
sum by (identifier,uri) ( custom_metric_total{identifier=~"${idenfiers}" )  * 0



Another way you could have solved this problem is by using a Merge Transformation. This has similar behavior, but with the added benefit of letting you merge data sets that come from different sources, like prometheus and SQL.
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#merge-seriestables

@BradCarter I tried using Merge, but seems like it works well when we use a Table Visualization where you have the common field column in both queries. In my case, I need to join 2 Timeseries on the URI.
